# Ionic app ask for location permission again after app update from playstore

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-permissions, android-location, ionic-native

I have an Ionic 3 app and published it on play store. I am using location permission to use users location in the map section. There I get pop up to allow the location permission and then I allow and it is working all fine.

I used 
`ionic cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic` and

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation --variable GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="To locate you"
```

these plugins to use location and manage permission of location access.

The issue is when I update the app from play store and then go to map section it is again asking me the location permission though I accepted it earlier (while first-time use of the app)

If anyone know more about this issue kindly help. 
any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think its an issue because you do an update and its normal for the user to accept the request.

Comment: @Sam Yes, but app doesn't ask permission again for the camera use which was also allowed before updating the app and after updating the app it works fine. It is happening just for the location permission

Comment: Because its not the same code  for them , in gps plugin there a some file for the request permissions and not in camera plugin. only in the manifest.